# How to prove equality with exponential function

Tags: proof-verification

How to prove this equality:

$$\frac{1-e^{-\frac{1}{t}}}{1-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}=1+e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}$$

I've no idea how to start so everything is welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Set $$e^{-1/2t}=u\implies e^{-1/t}=u^2$$

Comment: Or just multiply both sides by the denominator and use the fact that $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2$. Also the tag doesn't fit the question too well.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both sides with $1-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}$ is really all there is to it:
$$\frac{1-e^{-\frac{1}{t}}}{1-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}}=1+e^{-\frac{1}{2t}} \iff 1-e^{-\frac{1}{t}}=\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}\right)\left(1+e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}\right)$$
Now note that
$$\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}\right)\left(1+e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}\right)=1-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}+e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}-e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2t}}=1-e^{-2\cdot\frac{1}{2t}}=1-e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$$
And we are done :)